# Efficent Navigation using array

Tags: php, arrays, navigation

I am trying a different approach to my site navigation with a array stored in my `autoload.php` file, and the way I was thinking of was creating an array of `$site_data` - e.g `$site_data['title']`, `$site_data['url']`, `$site_data['cur_page']` etcetera; but I want to expand this to my site navigation using an array of `$navigation` and use it like `$navigation['text']`, `$navigation['url']`.

Here is my `autoload.php`:

```
<?php
//Define site property's
$site_data = [
    "title" => "Site Title",
    "ssl_browsing" => "0",
    "url" => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
    "page_url" => $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],
];
//Define site navigation
$navigation = [
    "title" => "Login",
    "page_link" => $site_data['url']."/webapp/login/",
];
```

I was going to use it like this...

```
for {
    $nav_title = $navigation['title'];
    $nav_link = $navigation['page_link'];
    $cur_url = $site_data[page_url];

    //Show li's
    echo "<li navActive($cur_url, $nav_link)><a href='$nav_link'>$nav_title</a></li>";
}
```

...and add a active class by doing something like this:

```
function navActive($cur_url, $nav_link) {
    if($nav_link == $cur_url) {
        echo "active";
    } else {

    }
}
```

Any help to help me make this work we be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Please check PHP guide and tutorials to write PHP. `for ($a;$b;$c; echo $x)`  is not a PHP construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only a "config" for your page, so, use direct PHP as template system,

```
 <html>
    <title><?php print $navigation['title']; ?></title>
    ...
 </html>
```

so, the PHP file (after `autoload.php` or including it) is a template where the placeholders are your `print $navigation['x']` variables.